# How can I bind a control's command to a child viewmodel command in an MVVM scenario?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a window in WPF based upon a viewmodel. The viewmodel includes a child viewmodel that can be switched at runtime. Each child viewmodel has its own commands. The parent view contains a ribbon with buttons that need to bind to the current child viewmodels commands. To switch views I use a content control in the parent view that uses data templates. Each possible child view is a user control that binds to the appropriate viewmodel (that bit works).

```
    <!-- Switchable area -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VersionsViewModel}">
                <embeddable:VersionsView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LockListViewModel}">
                <embeddable:LockListView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
```

So for example, one of my child viewmodels has a refresh command. I want this to appear in the main view in a ribbon button. I've tried setting the binding to the following XAML but it never binds so the command isn't called. What am I doing wrong?

```
<telerik:RadRibbonButton Size="Large"
                         Text="Refresh"
                         LargeImage="..\Images\Ribbon\32x32\Refresh.png"
                         Command="{Binding ChildView.RefreshCommand}" 
                         telerik:KeyTipService.AccessText="R"/>
```

Elsewhere in the main view I have bindings for data that comes from the child viewmodel and works fine so I'm really confused! For example, this is the binding I use to get the title for the window.

```
Title="{Binding ChildViewModel.Title,FallbackValue='My System'}"
```

Comment: The binding of the RibbonButtons Command-property has the Path `ChildView.`... against what the binding of your Title-property has the Path `ChildViewModel.`...

Comment: at least you can check the datacontext for your ribbon with Snoop to see what the actual datacontext for your ribbon is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<telerik:RadRibbonButton Size="Large"
                         Text="Refresh"
                         LargeImage="..\Images\Ribbon\32x32\Refresh.png"
                         Command="{Binding ChildViewModel.RefreshCommand}" 
                         telerik:KeyTipService.AccessText="R"/>
```

you weren't binding to the view model

Comment: D'Oh! I'm an idiot again :)  Thanks - I'd spent ages staring at it and not spotting that typo.